# What on earth is $ \mathcal{O} (\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What on earth is $ \mathcal{O} (\mathbb{C})$?
I used this in a project I hastily put together and now I cannot remember the definition of it. I checked in as many books as I still had with me and this symbol doesn't appear in any of them. But when I looked at the source *Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory, Volume 177* in Google Books I found only a piece of the puzzle as I couldn't look at the other pages anymore:

> For every region $D \in \mathbb{C}$, let $\mathcal{O}(\bar D)$ denote the set of all functions that are holomorphic in the open neighborhood $ \bar D = D \cup \delta D$

Am I right to assume that $\mathcal{O} (\mathbb{C})$ is just a symbol representing the set of all holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, the book is defining that symbol there.